# selected menuText color

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, uidefaults

I'm using a DefaultDockable, which has a menu bar with a title. I'm using Nimbus Look&Feel, and to set the text color of this title I'm using:

```
UIManager.put("menuText", Color.RED);
```

But what I don't know, is how to set the color when the menu is selected. Nimbus default for that is white, and I want to change it to black.

Having a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary),  I tried with `textHighlightText`,`controlLHighlight`, `nimbusSelectedText`, `nimbusLightBackground`, and even tried with `menuText[selected]`. None of them works for this.

How is it called for the selected menuText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
Menu[Enabled+Selected].textForeground
```

This site has a great display of the Nimbus defaults:

http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html